# how to send arraylist from android to server(wamp) usin php consisting of many records

Tags: php, android, mysql

i am sending the arraylist from android phone to server (wamp) using php.

this is the output of arraylist

03-04 12:46:54.588: I/System.out(477): calldata arraylist contents[tot_records=14, customer_id=abcd, phnumber=253647, type=OUTGOING, date=1/27/12 2:50:17 PM, duration=11, phnumber=456987, type=OUTGOING, date=1/27/12 3:41:02 PM, duration=9, phnumber=5554, type=OUTGOING, date=1/27/12 4:05:42 PM, duration=14]

i want to send this arraylist to server and retrieve it there but it is inserting only last record : phnumber=5554, type=OUTGOING, date=1/27/12 4:05:42 PM, duration=14

this is my java file:phpconnect.java

```
package your.database.namespace;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.util.Log;


 public class phpconnect
{
    public phpconnect(DatabaseActivity databaseActivity)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
 {
  // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
 try
 {  System.out.println("send data"+data);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/phpfiles/calllog.php");
    System.out.println(httppost);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
    System.out.println("send data2");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity http_entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(http_entity.getContent()));
String result = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(result);
       //Could do something better
 }
 catch(SocketException ex)
 {
  Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
  }  
  }}
```

this is my php file: calllog.php

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
echo $con;
if(!con)
{
    echo 'Not Connected......';
}
else
{
    echo 'CONNECTED.............';
}
$db=mysql_select_db('serverdb',$con);
 echo $db;
 if($db)
        {
           // return true;
echo "connection established";
        }
else
{ 
 echo "not conect";
}
$tot_records = $_POST["tot_records"];

$customer_id = $_POST["customer_id"];
echo $customer_id;
$i=($tot_records-2)/4;
echo $i;
//while(i>0)
//{
$number = $_POST["phnumber"];
$type = $_POST["type"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$duration = $_POST["duration"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO calllogdb (number,type,date,duration) 
    VALUES ('  $number','$type','$date' ,'$duration' )";
    $insert_result = mysql_query($query);

 if($insert_result)
 {
echo 'New Record Added !!';
}


 //$i--;
 //}

    //close the connection
    //mysqlEnd();

 ?>
```

Comment: you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the raw post data which get into PHP (use 
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input")
). This is presumably an XML format which is converted to a PHP array with field names as array keys. Since in your sample data the 3 records have the same field names, in the conversion to a PHP array each records overwrites the fields from the previous record in the array. Therefore only the last record gets stored.
And you will need a loop like the one which you commented out to process all entries.